# Including Guava GWT in GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, guava

I'm trying to add guava to my GWT 2.6.1 application. I included guava-19.0.jar and guava-gwt-19.0.jar.

I added 
`<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect" />

 <inherits name="com.google.common.base.Base" />` to my "MyApp.gwt.xml" file. When I go to run the app via Super Dev mode, I get this error, and I'm not sure what to do.

```
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Projects/my_proj/code/my_gwt_app/main_app/libs/guava/guava-gwt-19.0.jar!/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableAsList.java'
      [ERROR] Line 20: The import com.google.j2objc cannot be resolved
      [ERROR] Line 31: Weak cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] Compiler returned false
```

I have a single class that is using guava, and has the following imports:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
```

I'm not following what the "super" folder/package reference is to. I see a `com.google.common.collect.super.com.google.common.collect` package, but i'm not sure how to refer to it in my gwt.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the POM of `guava-gwt`, and you will see that it has its own dependencies, including j2objc.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.j2objc</groupId>
    <artifactId>j2objc-annotations</artifactId>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same message as Stealth Rabbi even after adding j2objc-annotations to my build path. Can't figure out why for the life of me.

Comment: Have you added inherit to the module's gwt.xml file?

Comment: I added <inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect" />. As best I can tell that's the only GWT module -- is there something else I'm supposed to inherit?