# Using Guava 20.0 in a GWT 2.8 project for dummys

Tags: gwt, guava

I am trying to use Guava 20.0 in a GWT 2.8 project, however I am getting errors when I try to compile;

```
 ...
     [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/common/base/Function.java'
        [ERROR] Line 64: CanIgnoreReturnValue cannot be resolved to a type
        [ERROR] Line 18: The import com.google.errorprone cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/common/base/Supplier.java'
 ...
```

And the solutions I find online;

[Including Guava GWT in GWT app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356031/including-guava-gwt-in-gwt-app)

https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9323

Are a little unclear to me.
Previously to get Guava working I added;

```
<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect" />.
```

To gwt.xml of my project.

I am assuming this has changed and I need to add two more? 
Or do I need to download separate *.jars as well? 
(and is there gwt versions of those jars I need to use like there is for guava-gwt?)

I apologize if there's some documentation I am missing regarding these changes to using guava, but all I can find on the guava site is reference to needing to use GWT2.8, which I am already.

So any advice on the current (November 2016) method to use the new Guava in new GWT would be welcome.
Thanks,

**Notes;** I am using Eclipse only, no Maven or Gradle etc.
My project is also client side only, no server.

Update;

Heres how my classpaths are setup;

[image: Eclipse classpaths setup]

Answer (score 1):

From [Guava's `pom.xml`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v20.0/guava-gwt/pom.xml), you need jsr305 (version 1.3.9, from the [parent POM](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v20.0/pom.xml)), error_prone_annotations (2.0.12), and j2objc-annotations (1.1).

You can download all of them from https://search.maven.org

See also https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2622

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded all 3 jars, although they don't seem to be usable with gwt? I cant see any *.gwt.xml files, so the inherits  statements fail.

Comment: They only contain annotations so I don't think you actually need GWT modules or even sources. Will have to check.

Comment: Thanks. If I put the jars on classpath (via eclipses interface), but don't add them to the inherits I get the original errors. So clearly some other step is needed here.
Oh, if it makes a difference; This is when I am trying to compile.

Comment: Still no luck. Maybe I am just setting something wrong. I have enclosed a image of my classpath setup.

Comment: Come to think of it, there is some differences in version between the  jars and the -source.jars.  (The maven repository doesn't seem to have version 1.3.9s source jar, for example).
Does this mater? Should I use the newer version for both?

Comment: I just tested quickly with Maven; project generated with `webAppCreator`, simply adding a dependency to `guava-gwt`, adding the `<inherits>` to the module and then using `ImmutableList` in the code. No error, not even a warning; no need for sources JAR for the annotations; and I'm compiling with `-failOnError` (aka `-strict`).

Comment: Just tried with Ant: classpath including gwt-dev, gwt-user, validation-api, validation-api sources (all four from the GWT SDK), guava-gwt, guava, jsr305, error_prone_annotations, and j2objc-annotations; and I can't reproduce the issue either. Maybe try deleting the `gwt-unitCache`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, following the advice here;
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/gPlwknBXlXs

It does work *sort of* if I create two identical gwt.xml files with contents;

```
<module>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />
<source path=""/>
<source path="concurrent"/>
<super-source path="super" />
</module>
```

I then place these files in packages;

```
com.google.errorprone.annotations
com.google.j2objc.annotations.Annotations
```

And add;

```
 <inherits name="com.google.errorprone.annotations.Annotations" />
 <inherits name="com.google.j2objc.annotations.Annotations" />
```

To my main projects gwt.xml

This works to get the project to compile, so technically it answers the question.

However;

a) It seems rather a hackjob.

b) While no errors, there is now a **huge**  number of warnings that still seems guava related.
For example;

```
Resolving com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultiset
  Found type 'com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultiset'
     Found type 'com.google.common.collect.AbstractMultiset'
        Resolving method add
           [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
        Resolving method add
           [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
        Resolving method remove
           [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
        Resolving method remove
        ...
        ...(many pages of this and identical errors in other classes)
```

For this reason I don't consider this question really answered yet, more that this is just a current workaround.